# Summation of series $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^k}{i+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to find a good tight approximation of the series
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^k}{i+1}$$

I have tried doing this

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^k}{i+1} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(i+1)^k}{i+1}$$
$$= \sum_{i=1}^{n} (i+1)^{k-1}$$
$$\leq n^k$$
$$= O(n^k)$$

But I think it can be made tighter. maybe some kind of log will be there? I couldn't figure out any way. Any ideas on this?

Comment: You could as well do $\frac{i^k}{i+1}\leq \frac{i^k}{i}$ to get slightly tighter $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{k-1}$, but of course this still gives $O(n^k)$

Comment: Yes, it's still $O(n^k)$

Comment: Not sure you can do anything better (asymptotically), consider $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^k}{i+1} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^k}{2i}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{k-1}$

Comment: For $k>0$, [Stolz–Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) implies $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^k}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j^k}{j+1}=\frac1k$.

Comment: Using the Euler-Maclaurin' formula it can be shown that, for example, for $k>3$ 
$$S_k=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^k}{i+1}$$
$$=\frac1kn^k+\left(\frac12-\frac1{k-1}\right)n^{k-1}+\left(\frac{k-1}{12}-\frac12+-\frac1{k-2}\right)n^{k-2}+O(n^{k-3})$$

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that $k$ is a positive integer $$S_k=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^k}{i+1}$$ let
$$T_k=\frac 1n \left(S_k -(-1)^{k-1}\,\left(1-\gamma-\psi (n+2)\right)\right)$$ where the $T_k$ are polynomials of degree $(k-1)$ in $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & \frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \\
 3 & \frac{n^2}{3}+\frac{2}{3} \\
 4 & \frac{n^3}{4}+\frac{n^2}{6}+\frac{n}{4}-\frac{2}{3} \\
 5 &
   \frac{n^4}{5}+\frac{n^3}{4}+\frac{n^2}{6}-\frac{n}{4}+\frac{
   19}{30} \\
 6 & \frac{n^5}{6}+\frac{3
   n^4}{10}+\frac{n^3}{6}-\frac{n^2}{6}+\frac{n}{6}-\frac{19}{3
   0} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This could (I hope and wish) give you some ideas.

If we look at the corresponding integrals
$$\int_1^n \frac{i^k}{i+1}\,di < S_k <\int_1^{n+1} \frac{i^k}{i+1}\,di $$ with
$$\int_1^n \frac{i^k}{i+1}\,di=(-1)^{k+1} B_{-n}(k+1,0)+\frac{1}{2} \left(H_{\frac{k-1}{2}}-H_{\frac{k}{2}}\right)$$
$$\int_1^{n+1} \frac{i^k}{i+1}\,di=(-1)^{k+1} B_{-n-1}(k+1,0)+\frac{1}{2} \left(H_{\frac{k-1}{2}}-H_{\frac{k}{2}}\right)$$  So, we have two bounds in terms of the incomplete beta function.

Trying for $k=5$ and $n=123$, the decimal value of the sum is
$5.68814\times 10^9$ while the bounds in term of the beta function are respectively $5.57400\times 10^9$ and $5.80477\times 10^9$ (look at the value of the mean of these two numbers).

Comment: Did the last part somehow go missing?

Comment: @Zarif. I forgot to delete it (what I shall do). For a given value of $k$, using Euler-MacLaurin summation, we can have very good approximations. But I did not fing a way to do it for general $k$ since I assumed that $k$ is a positive integer (then indefinite forms).

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @ClaudeLeibovici, Euler-Maclaurin summation can give a nice approximation, so let's do it!

Let
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i^k}{i+1} = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{i^k}{i+1}$$

This gives

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n f(i)  \sim \int_0^n f(x)dx + \frac{1}{2}f(0) + \frac{1}{2}f(n) + \frac{B_1}{2!} \left(f^{(1)}(n) - f^{(1)}(0) \right)
$$

with the Euler-Maclaurin summation where $f(x) = \frac{x^k}{k+1}$. The integral is evaluated as

$$
\int_0^n \frac{x^k}{k+1}dx = n^{k+1} \int_0^1 t^k(1+nt)^{-1}dt = \frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1} {}_2F_1(1,k+1;k+2;-n) = \frac{n^{k+1}}{(k+1)(n+1)} {}_2F_1\left(1,1;k+2;\frac{n}{n+1}\right) 
$$

by the substitution $t=x/n$ and then using a property of the hypergeometric function to achieve convergence (need $n/(n+1) < 1$).

This gives that

$$
S_n \sim  \frac{n^{k+1}}{(k+1)(n+1)} {}_2F_1\left(1,1;k+2;\frac{n}{n+1}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{n^k}{n+1}+\frac{1}{12}\frac{n^{k-1}(kn+k-n)}{(n+1)^2}
$$

This works for a larger set of $k$ and is not limited to integer values. I think this can be enlightening to compare to Claudes limits, for which (using the same values, i.e. $n=123, k=5$) gives that the the sum numerically is $5.6881394645\cdot 10^9$, whereas the approximation gives $5.6881394483\cdot10^9$, i.e. it is the 8th decimal which is different in the approximation.

Comment: This is nice ! (+1)